# URL rewritten but indexed as Query String

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I tried googling this but all it gave me was tutorials on how to rewrite so I thought I'd give it a shot asking it here.

The problem is that we have a htaccess file that rewrites the urls to a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+\/*[^\/]*\/*.*)$ index.php?app_route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works and it seems google is picking it up, however when you click on the link in google it shows the query string that it's rewritten to. We only link to the 'nice' urls so we don't know where google picked this up. Google for `site:sorellehaarmode.nl` to see for yourself.

Does anyone have experience with, or a solution to this problem?

Comment: When you go to the nice looking URL (the one without the query string), do you get redirected to the one with the query string?

Comment: No you won't get redirected (visibly). It just loads the index.php with the QS without the user seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules (anywhere to your current htaccess file, below the rules you already have is fine):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?app_route=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

This should permanently point the URLs with query strings to the ones without.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, it adds a question mark before the last letter of the route. `/kapsalons/sorelle-rotterdam-esmeijerplei?n`

Comment: @FERRYYY Sorry, the last `&?([^\ ]+)` in the condition should be `&?([^\ ]*)`. (replace `+` with `*`)